# How to make 6 partitions of table by 6 months and 7th partion of older than 6 month data?

Tags: mysql, partitioning, timestamp

we have a table structure with periodical data in a time-stamp column.
how to make 7 partition of this table with 7th portion as data older than 6 months.

I have already thought of running a cronjob and manually transferring the data to archive table if the above solution does not work out.

Comment: a good example of partitioning is here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/partition-maintenance/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible, but efficiently.  Only works for `PARTITION BY RANGE`.

Let's say you are starting to populate partition "2106_09" and need to migrate data in partition "2016_02" to partition "Older".  The command would be something like

```
ALTER TABLE tbl
    REORGANIZE PARTITION `2016_02`, `Older`  INTO (
        PARTITON `Older`  LESS THAN ('2016-03-01')
                 );
```

(Caveat: check the syntax.)

Note that you will need to construct this with a different partition name and "less than" each month.

But the problem is that it will rebuild "Older", which will take an amount of time based on how big it is.

[*This*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/partition-maintenance/) . may have some tips and code that is useful.